# Websites turn white in Ubuntu phone browser and webapps

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser, phone, webapps

I often experience that websites turn completely blank when using the browser or webapps on my Ubuntu phone. Sometimes it helps to restart the app but not always. Does someone know what is causing this? Any Ideas for fixes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's related to this bug with critical status, should be fixed by OTA 7: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-app-launch/+bug/1478853